# Error al concatenar me salen ceros

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

Estoy realizando una concatenación de dos campos pero al momento de convertirlo a CSV me coloca puros ceros. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
replace pedposdoc WITH ALLTRIM(pedpos)+ALLTRIM(STR(docmat)) all
```

Hasta ahi todo va perfecto cuando uso el comando y ejecuto me salen correcto y me lo concatena bien pero al momento de ejecutarlo para que me lo convierta a CSV reviso el Doc y me salen puros ceros por ejemplo

Al ejecutarlo en el comando

```
PEDDOC                  PED                 DOC
5003497654510           500349765           4510
```

Al realizar todo y que se pase al CSV

```
PEDDOC                 PED                 DOC
5003497650000          500349765           4510
```

Alguien podría ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Ale, no dudo que alguien podrá ayudarte con tu problema. En el futuro será mejor que no uses mayúsculas en tu pregunta, ya que eso sugiere que estas gritando. He editado tu pregunta para cambiar eso. Por lo demás, bienvenida a SOes. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias :3 
Lo lamento eso no lo sabía lo de las mayúsculas, lo tomaré en cuenta